# shape_predictor in dlib module ArgumentError when using relative paths

Tags: python, python-2.7, dlib, python-os

I have come across a strange error when using `dlib.shape_predictor` function.

This is my code:

```
import sys
import dlib
from skimage import io
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import os


predictor_model = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__),"Models","shape_predictor_68_face_landmarks.dat")

# Take the image file name from the command line
file_name = "/home/matt/Programming/Python/Face_detection/Images/wedding_photo.jpg"

# Test if they are equivalent
print predictor_model == "/home/matt/Programming/Python/Face_detection/Models/shape_predictor_68_face_landmarks.dat"

predictor_model = "/home/matt/Programming/Python/Face_detection/Models/shape_predictor_68_face_landmarks.dat"

# Create a HOG face detector using the built-in dlib class
face_detector = dlib.get_frontal_face_detector()
face_pose_predictor = dlib.shape_predictor(predictor_model)
```

If I use the predictor model as defined through relative path using `os` then I get an error:

```
ArgumentError: Python argument types in
    shape_predictor.__init__(shape_predictor, unicode)
did not match C++ signature:
    __init__(boost::python::api::object, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >)
    __init__(_object*)
```

If I hardcode the path as defined above the script runs without a problem. Any ideas what may have gone wrong?

Comment: did you by chance solve your problem?

Comment: @fonfonx No I think I sidestepped the issue by re-creating this code on a windows machine. Sorry!